# Scheduled task in SCDF with Kubernetes persistent volume

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task, kubernetes-cronjob

I'm trying to run a Task in SCDF on minikube. This task extracts data from a database and write them into a file. So I use a local persistent volume I configured in Kubernetes Dashboard to get my file.
It works fine when I run a simple execution with deployer parameters :

> deployer.my-task.kubernetes.volumes=[ { name: vol-data, persistentVolumeClaim: {claimName: 'pv-data-claim'}} ]
>   deployer.my-task.kubernetes.volumeMounts=[ { name: 'vol-data', mountPath: '/data' } ]

When I look at the pod yaml file, I see my volume properties :

```
spec:   
  volumes:
    - name: vol-data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: pv-data-claim
```

and

```
   volumeMounts:
     - name: vol-data
       mountPath: /data
```

And I get my file in my local directory at the end of the execution.

But when I tried to create a scheduled task with the same parameters, it doesn't work. I didn't see my volume properties in the cronjob yaml or in the pod launched by the cronjob and of course I didn't get my file.

Am I missing something ? I was thinking that launching a simple task or scheduled task from SCDF would be the same

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the scheduling support in SCDF doesn't include the `persistentVolumeClaim` support yet *[see: [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-scheduler-kubernetes#21](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-scheduler-kubernetes/issues/21)]*.

We have an open issue to bring the Scheduler up to the same level as regular app deployment or task launches. Feel free to subscribe to the notifications/updates: [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes#331](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes/issues/331).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Hope this will be released soon